# How to sign a XML document that contains special characters, in java?

Tags: java, xml, certificate, digital-signature

I am signing a XML document that contains special characters (non-ASCII characters, like ã, á, à, ç, etc), in a java class that is called by PeopleSoft system. To avoid any problems, I remove these characters, but in fact I need to print this signed document with them. Is there any way to do this? This is a sample of the XML document to be signed (it is ready for signature):

```
<PedidoEnvioLoteRPS xmlns="http://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/nfe" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Cabecalho Versao="1" xmlns="">
    <CPFCNPJRemetente>
      <CNPJ>99999999999999</CNPJ>
    </CPFCNPJRemetente>
    <transacao>false</transacao>
    <dtInicio>2018-10-02</dtInicio>
    <dtFim>2018-10-02</dtFim>
    <QtdRPS>1</QtdRPS>
    <ValorTotalServicos>40</ValorTotalServicos>
    <ValorTotalDeducoes>0</ValorTotalDeducoes>
  </Cabecalho>
  <RPS xmlns="">
    <Assinatura>FavH23VVIbPWzlvJ28OZZ26Lv2aEgWfmsdhPN1qQN19UCxv6xzu8fHC50wnji3i3G49DuYoXy354U2IxzooPtZYWv7KFUwWLWC4xJYpNKNLOg3txx4znxDNbdC9l/ot9liIMKHf/8rJdciGMpwUOMxt3z95sFVJDcvx/3si1yQG0TaQsWLLLKHH4rUwfE+OWYBIwp/CWBf1/IRzYsFb/q2UgpvfvU1RaXIgI+aNqwYyKulhfUZItI4nYJTsGcXG0y+iXxW3oRWiCGJ5leOysHyJ4VLJcg/vehwT8f8ZQLhvClKeDQUQpL9ts+9oX4PHdc8WXDgN5ekUmvCHS/GW0ew==</Assinatura>
    <ChaveRPS>
      <InscricaoPrestador>99999999</InscricaoPrestador>
      <SerieRPS>1</SerieRPS>
      <NumeroRPS>180</NumeroRPS>
    </ChaveRPS>
    <TipoRPS>RPS</TipoRPS>
    <DataEmissao>2018-10-02</DataEmissao>
    <StatusRPS>N</StatusRPS>
    <TributacaoRPS>T</TributacaoRPS>
    <ValorServicos>40</ValorServicos>
    <ValorDeducoes>0</ValorDeducoes>
    <CodigoServico>3205</CodigoServico>
    <AliquotaServicos>2</AliquotaServicos>
    <ISSRetido>false</ISSRetido>
    <CPFCNPJTomador>
      <CNPJ>88888888888888</CNPJ>
    </CPFCNPJTomador>
    <RazaoSocialTomador>XPTO S.A.</RazaoSocialTomador>
    <EnderecoTomador>
      <Logradouro>Av do Lago</Logradouro>
      <NumeroEndereco>999</NumeroEndereco>
      <ComplementoEndereco>9 andar - cj. 99</ComplementoEndereco>
      <Bairro>Vila Guilherme</Bairro>
      <Cidade>3505708</Cidade>
      <UF>SP</UF>
      <CEP>99999999</CEP>
    </EnderecoTomador>
    <EmailTomador>teste@teste.com.br</EmailTomador>
    <Discriminacao>Tarifa de antecipação de entrega VR Saúde Familiar: R$ 40,00||||||||||||||||IRRF 1,5% Sob Responsabilidade de VR Benefícios Serv  Proc Ltda conforme I.N. 153/87 e |Lei 7450/85, art. 53 - R$ 0,60|Trib aprox. Lei nº 12.741/12: R$5,38 Federal, R$1,68 Municipal e R$32,94 pelos serviços|Fonte:IBPT/empresometro.com.br  A3S28F 18.2.B|Contrato XPTO|Autorização de Regime especial - SEI 6017.2018/0055420-5 (32600,94)|REALIZE O PAGAMENTO APENAS DE BOLETOS EMITIDOS POR VOCÊ NA ÁREA LOGADA E SEGURA DO SEU|PORTAL RH. PREVINA-SE E EVITE PREJUÍZOS FINANCEIROS.</Discriminacao>
    <ValorCargaTributaria>7.06</ValorCargaTributaria>
    <PercentualCargaTributaria>17.64</PercentualCargaTributaria>
    <FonteCargaTributaria>IBPT</FonteCargaTributaria>
  </RPS>

</PedidoEnvioLoteRPS>
```

The java method that I use to sign is:

```
public void AssinaXML(String ArqAssinar) {

    try {
        /* Creates the DOM document DOM from the file in ArqAssinar */
        DocumentBuilderFactory DocBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder DocBuilder = DocBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        FileInputStream Input = new FileInputStream(ArqAssinar);
        Document Doc = DocBuilder.parse(Input);

        /* Gets the position of the Signature tag */
        Node Tag = Doc.getDocumentElement();

        if (Tag != null) {
            /* Signs the document */
            DOMSignContext DocSignCont = new DOMSignContext(PrivPass, Tag);
            XMLSignature Signature = XmlSignFac.newXMLSignature(SignInfo, KeyInf);
            Signature.sign(DocSignCont);

            /* Creates the Signature tag with the results */
            OutputStream Saida = new FileOutputStream(ArqAssinar);
            TransformerFactory TransformFac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer Transf = TransformFac.newTransformer();
            Transf.transform(new DOMSource(Doc), new StreamResult(Saida));  
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Java Assinatura_Digital, método AssinaXML - A tag especificada para inserir a assinatura não foi encontrada");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception E) {
        E.PrintStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I have this error when I try to sign the XML document above:

> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
>     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at GVR_Assinatura_Digital.AssinaXML(GVR_Assinatura_Digital.java:551)
>       at GVR_Assinatura_Digital.main(GVR_Assinatura_Digital.java:778)

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Singing XML don't care XML document content at all, you can sign a XML document with your special characters like `&nbsp;` or `&euro;` for example

Comment: Hi Victor, thank you for your support. But I think I did not explain it right. The special characters, in my case, are non-ASCII characters (like á, ã, ç, etc.). I need to maintain these characters in document.

Comment: there should be no reason why you would need to remove the special characters in order to sign the document.  as long as it is valid xml, you should be able to sign it.  what is the problem that you are encountering?

Comment: Hi jtahlborn. When I tried to sign without remove that characters, I had this error:  Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: @Roberto, add the code you are using to sign, and the entire stack trace of the error. Without this information nobody can answer your question

Comment: XML has nothing to do with ASCII. All XML characters are Unicode. (There is a _short_ list of Unicode _control_ characters that aren't allowed directly in XML.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have said, you can sign any valid XML document.

So the real question should be, **How do I create a valid XML document that includes characters like ã?**

Answer:

- By default, XML documents are encoded in UTF-8
- So you can directly add any character to an XML document via UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character sequence. The following is a valid XML document:

UTF-8 encoding

```
<test>Ã¥</test>
```

- You can also include characters as character entities. But once you have your characters as UTF-8 there is no need to convert them to character entities.

If you have problems creating a valid XML document that includes non-ASCII characters, please create a new Stack Overflow question that includes the code snippet that is (or should) be creating the XML file.

Also see:

[Microsoft article on encoding characters in XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468560.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Hi Larry. Actually, I am using a java class that I created within another system, and this system creates the XML document. The java class just sign this document.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution: I just traded this:

```
FileInputStream Input = new FileInputStream(ArqAssinar);
Document Doc = DocBuilder.parse(Input);
```

for this:

```
InputStream Input = new FileInputStream(ArqAssinar);
Reader Leitor = new InputStreamReader(Input, "UTF-8");
InputSource Origem = new InputSource(Leitor);
Document Doc = DocBuilder.parse(Origem);
```